# Obtaining an old REST Session key

Tags: session, facebook-rest-api

Because facebook hasn't migrated certain functions over to GRAPH yet, I still need to make some calls via REST.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to obtain a REST session key for users who accept my application today.

Is there ANY way to request a REST session key from facebook?  I make almost all of my calls via GRAPH, but until they finish migrating features I'm stuck without one....

Thanks in advance!

DW

Comment: What hasn't been migrated? As far as i know everything was moved to Graph API

Comment: try to do links.preview, for example.

Comment: I've never heard of that before just now, i suspect it's no longer supported but should still work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All REST API methods which required a session key should just fine with an access token.

I just tested the links.preview method you mentioned before:

`https://api.facebook.com/method/links.preview?url=http://www.google.com&format=json&access_token=<REMOVED>`

Response was:

```
    {
   "href":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/",
   "name":"Google",
   "caption":"www.google.com",
   "description":"Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.",
   "media":[
      {
         "type":"image",
         "src":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/intl\/en_ALL\/images\/srpr\/logo1w.png"
      },
      {
         "type":"image",
         "src":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/google_favicon_128.png"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: that's very interesting.  I had tried something like that in the past without success.  I wonder if they've caught up with me after all this time.  I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey igy -- I try that myself (finally) and I get back "Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API" from facebook.  I'm curious why this works for you and not for me....

Comment: Are you using a user access token? You need to

Comment: it's actually a page access token.  I don't always have a user access token on-hand, so I execute calls as a page.  I guess that's my problem, huh?  Rats.  I was so close....

Comment: Yep, you can only use page tokens with the Graph API, not the old REST API

Comment: Well I'm accepting the answer because you're right, I'm just asking for the impossible....